# Can't get JButton to be clicked more than once bluej

Tags: java, jbutton, action, actionlistener

When I run my main inside of the ButtonSample class the button pops up and works as intended but it can't be clicked more than once. What causes this to happen and what should I change to make this work properly and have the button able to be clicked more than once. Is it something to do with my actionListener. Also when I try to click the exit button the button doesn't close until I reset Java Virtual Machine, how would i fix that too.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class ButtonSample extends JFrame implements ActionListener  
{  
    String[] et = {};
    JButton button1;
    public ButtonSample() throws IOException 
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(100, 100);
        setLocation(100, 100);

        button1 = new JButton("GO");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        add(button1);

        setVisible(true);
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
         new ButtonSample();
    }

    @Override
    public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) //throws IOException
    {
        try{
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        String[] arr = {};

        if(command.equals("GO")) {
        tester.main(arr);

    }
    }catch(IOException io){ }
  }
}



public class tester 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String[] err = {};
        try
        {
          boolean go = true;
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          while(go)
          {
            Reader r = new Reader();
            Three t = new Three();
            String[] run = {};
            String[] list = Reader.main(run);
            int one = t.get1();
            int two = t.get2();
            int three = t.get3();
            t.check(one, two, three);
            System.out.println("The three names are...");
            System.out.println(list[one] + "    " + list[two] + "    " +       list[three]);
            System.out.print("Play again?(Y/N): ");
            String check = in.next();
            if(check.equals("n") || check.equals("N"))
            {
               go = false;
               System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.print('\u000C');
          }
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) 
          {
              System.out.print('\u000C');
              tester.main(err);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: `catch(IOException io){ }`???

Comment: I have to throw the IOException inside of another class so I put that there because I could think of any other way to get the actionPerformed class to throw it.

Comment: @vlovero ok but empty catch block is not  good

Comment: I have no criticism of your catching the exception -- but you're completely ignoring the catch block -- why?? Your program could be blowing up and you're ignoring anything that would tell you *why* it's blowing up. It's extremely foolish code. At the very least, print the stacktrace.

Comment: I left it empty because honestly I didn't know what to put in it...

Comment: Again, at least print the stack trace, something like, `io.printStackTrace();`, and then tell us if it reports a problem. And then find a tutorial on how to handle exceptions because this is key knowledge: [Google java handle exception](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LEND_enUS445US445&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+handling+exception+) -- first hit.

Comment: It didn't report a problem when I ran it.

Comment: I removed tester.amin(arr), changed the IOException with Exception and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `tester.main(arr);`. I tried running your code without it and the button works fine.

```
public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) //throws IOException
{
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        String[] arr = {};

        if(command.equals("GO")) {
        //  tester.main(arr);
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
}
```

Please provide us the code for tester.main.

Comment: Do you need the the rest of the classes too or is the tester enough?

Comment: @vlovero. Ok. It's good to hear that you found the main issue and solved it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Tordek. It's better to place it as answer because I want to show some codes. Codes can't be formatted well in comments.